# Как запустить кусок кода js из php?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Есть обработчик на jQuery, который при клике на кнопку "hide" сворачивает определенные элементы:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
$('.hide').click(function() { ... })
...
});
```

Мне надо сделать так, что при первом входе на сайт у пользователя этот кусок был как обычно развернут, а при повторном входе уже свернут, я это пытаюсь сделать через сессии:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
      здесь надо выполнить действие кнопки "hide"
    }
    $_SESSION['name'] = "test";
 ?>
```

Подскажите как это можно реализовать? 
В обработчике кнопки довольно много чего, может его можно обернуть как-то в функцию и вызывать из php?

Comment: я тоже задавался этим вопросом но ответа не получил , + вам и жду ответа с вами

Comment: если на уровне сессии то можно  заменить на localStorage

Comment: https://toster.ru/q/326025  вот твой вопрос на toster , следим вместе

Comment: https://otvet.mail.ru/question/191055574  вот тоже на mail.ru

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['first_in'])){
    ?>
    <script src="libs/jquery/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="common.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.hide').trigger('click');
        }); 
    </script>
<?php
}
$_SESSION['first_in'] = "first_in_ok";
?>
```

Разобрался)

Answer (score 0):

```html
if(isset($_SESSION['perviy_vhod'])){
  echo '<script>
    $(function(){
      $('.hide').trigger('click');
    }); 
  </script>';
  $_SESSION['perviy_vhod'] = 'perviy_vhod_vipolnen';
}
```

источник https://toster.ru/q/326025

Comment: Ошибка:
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: получается что вы что то не сделали с $ , т.е вот этой perviy_vhod

Comment: нет, он ругается что $ не объявлена, которая перед (function()), пробовал там прописывать jQuery, начинает ругаться на jQuery

Comment: на источник смотрите , я там ваш вопрос продублировал , и на майле но там молчок , на тостере - я ж говорил что я задавал этот вопрос

Comment: not defined это не объявлена - соответственно вы указали переменную но не описали её , а js там указывать не надо - js вызывается